# Understanding the structure of SharePoint online compared to previous on-prem versions

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection, site

I used to work with an on-premise SharePoint server some time ago. This was when there were `Site Collections` which could be created using the `Central Administration`, and where I was able to add `Sites` to it.

So the resulting structure or *hierarchy* was like

```
Site Collection A
     > Site B
     > Site C
       > Subsite D
```

How is this done in SharePoint online? In the administration, all I can see is the possibility to create new `Sites`. No `Site Collections`. No `Subsites`.

Is there any hierarchy, or are there only `Sites` in SharePoint Online which are all at the same level?

[This documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sites/plan-sites-and-site-collections) explicitly excludes SharePoint Online from the structural planning. Might this be an indicator that it works in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In reality not much have changed since last time you worked with SharePoint (from on prem to online) and then again... everything has changed!

But, the "sites" that you can create from the admin in SharePoint Online in reality are site collection, that can have several subsites (collections). The sub sites are created from the gui on the site (or from script etc) and not from the admin control area.

However, it is strongly encouraged to not use sub sites, but instead plan an information architecture where sites are bound together with the new "Hub site" feature, where you assign a site to be a hub site, and then assign others to connect to that hub site (you can have hundred or thousands of hub sites, so no need to not create them from a limitation perspective). All sites in a hub will share navigation, permissions (optional) and you can roll up content from the sites to the hub.

So depending on your scenario you might want to check it out: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-a-sharepoint-hub-site-fe26ae84-14b7-45b6-a6d1-948b3966427f

Welcome back to SharePoint btw :)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with RuneBH. In SharePoint Online, we recommend not to use subsites.

**For more information about Navigation Structure, you can read the below articles:**

- [Navigation options for SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/navigation-options-for-sharepoint-online?view=o365-worldwide)
- [Plan and implement SharePoint site navigation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/plan-navigation-modern-experience)